# How many different three-digit house numbers could be made?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

a shopkeeper sells house numbers. she has a large supply of the numerals 4, 7 and 8, but no other numerals. how many different three-digit house numbers could be made using only the numerals in her supply?

Answer (score 2):

The first digit has three options. The second digit again has three options. So far we could have 44-, 47-, 48-, 74-, 77-, 78-, 84-, 87-, 87-. As you can see, we have $3*3$ options. This pattern continues, and for three digits we have $3*3*3=27$ options.